# Edit Set-Cookie header only on specific redirects

Tags: apache

In some cases my web application responses with a redirect (302) to another application and simultanously sets a cookie to the user Browser. What I want is apache to catch the "Set-Cookie" header and alter it (eg. make the cookie secure). However, I want this to happen only for redirects to a specific domain. For all the other redirects I want the cookie to remain untouched:

```
<if response is redirect to http://my.certain.domain.gr> <-How to implement this condition?
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;Secure;
```

This needs to be done (if possible) within apache configuration rather that altering the application code for reasons that are out of my responsibility.

How can this be achieved in apache?

Comment: Take a look at [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)